# Spring and editable "WHERE" @Query

Tags: java, spring

is even possible create something like this ?

```
 @Query(value = """
            SELECT Name
            FROM Users
            WHERE :column = :value
                   """, nativeQuery = true)
 List<Users> getValue(@Param("column") String column, @Param("value") String name);
```

and change where "column" for column what I want.
userRepository.getVale("name","Mike");

So that one query can be used for more options

Answer (score 1, accepted):

with `mybatis` you can do this

```java
import org.apache.ibatis.annotations.Param;
import org.apache.ibatis.annotations.Select;

@Select("select * from table where ${column} = #{value}")
List<Users> selectUsersByColumnValue(@Param("column")String column, @Param("value")String value);
```

Pay attention to the risk of SQL injection of `${column}`

Answer (score 2):

with `querydsl` you can do this

```
private final JPAQueryFactory queryFactory;
QUser user = QUser.user;

public List<String> selectUserByColumnValue(String column, String value) {
    return queryFactory.select(user.username)
            .from(user)
            .where(eqColumn(column, value))
            .fetch();
}

private BooleanExpression eqColumn(String column, String value) {
    if (column.equals("username")) {
        return user.username.eq(value);
    }
    if (column.equals("password")) {
        return user.password.eq(value);
    }
    // blah blah
    return null;
}
```